# What is a best way to export high quality Corel X5 figure ready for word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, coreldraw

I have problem with exporting figures from Corel X5. When I am using .tiff file is too large and I have problem with handling in word. If I export it in other format, figure is not with good quality. Figure is with 2 colours and many crossed lines. Do you have idea or example what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only vector formats that Word supports are [EPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) and [WMF/EMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile). So instead of exporting to a raster format use one of these and your document should hopefully look (or at least print) fine.

Note that for best results you might have to increase the size of your vector image by 5x (perhaps even more) before exporting, so that fine detail looks better in Word. Also, different programs seem to generate EPS/EMF files of varying quality (sometimes not well-formed), so you'll probably need to experiment before you figure out (pun intended :) what works best for you.

Finally, I'd suggest looking into using a format like PDF (that has better support for vector graphics) instead of Word documents. If you must edit in Word for some reason, perhaps you can export to PDF once you're done and insert your vector images as the last step of your workflow.

Comment: thank you very much for full answer. I did some experiments and I was not satisfied with quality. So your suggestion is to deal with exported .pdf file. So how to do that? First to finish word document and on the end to do import from word?

Comment: Yes, once you're done editing Word should allow you to save as PDF (for older versions you might need the Save as PDF/XPS add-on). There are also free/paid PDF printer drivers that might generate better quality PDFs. Or else perhaps you can use Adobe Acrobat or similar and skip Word altogether.

Comment: thank you Karan. But for example in Adobe Acrobat XI how can I type equations?

Comment: I haven't used Acrobat extensively myself, so I don't know if newer versions have this capability. Long time back I do remember using MathType (bigger brother of Word's Equation Editor) to generate PDFs with equations and moving those equation objects between PDFs using Acrobat. Complex equations generated using LaTeX can also be exported to PS or PDF.

Comment: Karan I have problem with .pdf figure, after drag and drop into word worksheet figure doesn't look like nice.

Comment: I don't get it. You inserted a PDF into Word? How?

Comment: I have vector figure in Corel, and after printing in .pdf file figure looks like nice. When I wanted to import .pdf figure to another .pdf text file, Adobe didn't allow me .pdf file of image?

Comment: When you printed to PDF, did it just convert it to a bitmap image and embed it into the PDF, like a scanned image? I don't know about Corel, so you'll have to find out how to export as vector to PDF. If you can't figure it out feel free to post a new question that hopefully a Corel expert will answer.

Comment: yes Karan, like scanned image but quality is perfect.